# imagettftext() function not working?

Tags: php, gd

I input this code to show text convert into image.

```
<?php
// Set the content-type
header('Content-Type:image/png');

// Create the image
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(400, 30);

// Create some colors
$white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
$grey = imagecolorallocate($im, 128, 128, 128);
$black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
 imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, 399, 29, $white);

// The text to draw
$text = 'Testing...';
// Replace path by your own font path
$font="arial.ttf";

// Add some shadow to the text
imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 11, 21, $grey, $font, $text);

// Add the text
imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 10, 20, $black, $font, $text);

// Using imagepng() results in clearer text compared with imagejpeg()
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

And after this the OUTPUT is::

[Output in mozilla](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5t0Y.png)

I'm using WAMP in windows and also GD installed... My gd_info() :

```
array (size=12)
'GD Version' => string 'bundled (2.1.0 compatible)' (length=26)
'FreeType Support' => boolean true
'FreeType Linkage' => string 'with freetype' (length=13)
'T1Lib Support' => boolean false
'GIF Read Support' => boolean true
'GIF Create Support' => boolean true
'JPEG Support' => boolean true
'PNG Support' => boolean true
'WBMP Support' => boolean true
'XPM Support' => boolean true
'XBM Support' => boolean true
'JIS-mapped Japanese Font Support' => boolean false
```

So finally what I have to do... Please help me......

Comment: Have you tried looking at the file in an editor?

Comment: You have to make sure the font is in the directory you're running (to facilitate things)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Try my code...  create one php file->put this code and just run you
>   got result surely...  happy codding....

Don't Forgot To add "arial.ttf" file where you run your php file same directory...

```
 <?php
        // Set the content-type
        header('Content-Type: image/png');

        // Create the image
        $im = imagecreatetruecolor(400, 30);

        // Create some colors
        $white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
        $grey = imagecolorallocate($im, 128, 128, 128);
        $black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
        imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, 399, 29, $white);

        // The text to draw
        $text = 'Testing...';
        // Replace path by your own font path
        $font = 'arial.ttf';

        // Add some shadow to the text
        imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 11, 21, $grey, $font, $text);

        // Add the text
        imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 10, 20, $black, $font, $text);

        // Using imagepng() results in clearer text compared with imagejpeg()
        imagepng($im);
        imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

Comment: i think... there you forgot to pur arial.ttf file

Comment: It looked similar to the original code. How come now it works? Care to explain? OP said arial.ttf already exist in same directory as script.

Comment: don't know... but believe me my when I enter my previous code it doesn't works but when I input this one it works

Answer (score 2):

you need to specify the full path to the font file.

and give 755 permission to the font file

```php
class CaptchaSecurityImages {

    var $font = 'monofont.ttf';

    function getFontPath(){
        return $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/captcha/monofont.ttf';
    }

    function generateCode($characters) {
        /* list all possible characters, similar looking characters and vowels have been removed */
        $possible = '012345678';
        $code = '';
        $i = 0;
        while ($i < $characters) { 
            $code .= substr($possible, mt_rand(0, strlen($possible)-1), 1);
            $i++;
        }
        return $code;
    }

    function CaptchaSecurityImages($width='120',$height='40',$characters='6') {
        $code = $this->generateCode($characters);
        /* font size will be 75% of the image height */
        $font_size = $height * 0.75;
        $image = @imagecreate($width, $height) or die('Cannot initialize new GD image stream');
        /* set the colours */
        $background_color = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255);
        $text_color = imagecolorallocate($image, 20, 40, 100);
        $noise_color = imagecolorallocate($image, 100, 120, 180);
        /* generate random dots in background */
        for( $i=0; $i<($width*$height)/3; $i++ ) {
            imagefilledellipse($image, mt_rand(0,$width), mt_rand(0,$height), 1, 1, $noise_color);
        }
        /* generate random lines in background */
        for( $i=0; $i<($width*$height)/150; $i++ ) {
            imageline($image, mt_rand(0,$width), mt_rand(0,$height), mt_rand(0,$width), mt_rand(0,$height), $noise_color);
        }
        /* create textbox and add text */
        $textbox = imagettfbbox($font_size, 0, $this->getFontPath(), $code) or die('Error in imagettfbbox function');
        $x = ($width - $textbox[4])/2;
        $y = ($height - $textbox[5])/2;
        imagettftext($image, $font_size, 0, $x, $y, $text_color, $this->getFontPath() , $code) or die('Error in imagettftext function');
        /* output captcha image to browser */
        header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
        imagejpeg($image);
        imagedestroy($image);
        $_SESSION['security_code'] = $code;
    }

}

$width = isset($_GET['width']) ? $_GET['width'] : '120';
$height = isset($_GET['height']) ? $_GET['height'] : '40';
$characters = isset($_GET['characters']) && $_GET['characters'] > 1 ? $_GET['characters'] : '6';

$captcha = new CaptchaSecurityImages($width,$height,$characters);
```

Answer (score 0):

If it worked after you comment to both call to imagettftext(), make sure file arial.ttf exists in same directory of script. Also comment out call to header() to be able to view any error message returned.

Comment: try change 'arial.ttf' to 'arial'

Comment: From documentation http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php "Depending on which version of the GD library PHP is using, when fontfile does not begin with a leading / then .ttf will be appended to the filename and the library will attempt to search for that filename along a library-defined font path. "